# Metadata, content-length for GCS objects

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, pre-signed-url

Two things:

1. I am trying to set custom metadata on a GCS object signed URL.
2. I am trying to set a maximum file size on a GCS object signed URL.

Using the following code:

```
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put("x-goog-meta-" + usernameKey, username);

    if (StringUtils.hasText(purpose)) {
      headers.put("x-goog-meta-" + purposeKey, purpose);
    }

    if (maxFileSizeMb != null) {
      headers.put("x-goog-content-length-range", String.format("0,%d", maxFileSizeMb * 1048576));
    }

    List<Storage.SignUrlOption> options = new ArrayList<>();
    options.add(Storage.SignUrlOption.httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST));
    options.add(Storage.SignUrlOption.withExtHeaders(headers));

    String documentId = documentIdGenerator.generateDocumentId().getFormatted();
    StorageDocument storageDocument =
        StorageDocument.builder().id(documentId).path(getPathByDocumentId(documentId)).build();
    storageDocument.setFormattedName(documentId);

    SignedUrlData.SignedUrlDataBuilder builder =
        SignedUrlData.builder()
            .signedUrl(storageInterface.signUrl(gcpStorageBucket, storageDocument, options))
            .documentId(documentId)
            .additionalHeaders(headers);
```

First of all the generated signed URL works and I can upload a document.

Now I am expecting to see the object metadata through the console view. There is no metadata set though. Also the `content-length-range` is not respected. I can upload a 1.3 MB file when the `content-length-range` is set to `0,1`.

Something happens when I upload a bigger file (~ 5 MB), but within the `content-length-range`. I receive an error message: `Metadata part is too large.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/signatures#:%7E:text=Content%20Length%20Range) `content-length-range` requires both a minimum and maximum size. The unit used for the range is bytes, as you can see in [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/signatures#policy-document-example) example.

I also noticed that you used `x-goog-content-length-range`, I found [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-headers#xgoogcontentlengthrange) documentation for it, when using this header take into account:

1. Use a `PUT` request, otherwise it will be silently ignored.
2. If the size of the request's content is outside the specified range, the request fails and a 400 Bad Request code is returned in the response.
3. You have to set the minimum and maximum size in bytes.

Comment: Thanks. I already fixed that though. Still metadata is not set and limits are not respected.

Comment: However, I just re-read the docs (thank you) and apparently the header only works on PUT requests.

Comment: Glad to help. I will update my answer to add you findings.